# React-native : show content on two rows

Tags: react-native

I want to show 6 options per row instead of showing only one option per row.
I'm still new in react-native
Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from 'src/components';
import Option from './OptionVariable';
import {checkOption} from 'src/modules/product/helper';
import {margin} from 'src/components/config/spacing';

class AttributeVariable extends React.Component {
  onSelectOption = (option) => {
    const {onSelectAttribute, attribute} = this.props;
    onSelectAttribute(attribute.get('id'), attribute.get('name'), option.get('option'));
  };
  render() {
    const {attribute, meta_data, variations} = this.props;
    // Attribute selected
    const attributeSelected = meta_data.find(attr => attr.get('id') === attribute.get('id') && attr.get('name') === attribute.get('name'));

    return (
      <>
        <Text>
          {attribute.get('name')}: <Text colorSecondary>{attributeSelected ? attributeSelected.get('option') : ''}</Text>
        </Text>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.attribute}
          vertical
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {attribute.get('options').map(option => {
            const disabled = meta_data.size === 0 ? false : !checkOption(variations, meta_data, fromJS({
              id: attribute.get('id'),
              name: attribute.get('name'),
              option: option.get('option'),
            }));

            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={disabled ? 1 : 0}
                key={option}
                onPress={() => disabled ? {} : this.onSelectOption(option)}
              >
                <Option
                  type={attribute.get('type')}
                  selected={attributeSelected && option.get('option') === attributeSelected.get('option')}
                  disabled={disabled}
                  option={option}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })}
        </ScrollView>

      </>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  attribute: {
    marginTop: margin.small,
  },
});

export default AttributeVariable;
```

Here is how it looks :

[image]

[image]

I hope everything is clear to you.
Sorry for my bad english it's not my main language....
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

you can say in your attribute style:

```
attribute: {
 marginTop: margin.small,
 flexDirection: 'row'
},
```

so it should align in rows instead of columns

That should help you to learn more about styling components in react native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same result and that did not work.

Comment: It continuous in columns? could you show the code of Option components? Maybe trying to remove vertical props of ScrollView, do you want it in horizontal right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Flatlist (instead of ScrollView) component passing the horizontal={true} props.

Like this:

```
FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    data={attribute.option}
    renderItem={({ item }) => "Pass your component"}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2 :**
I used `View` instead of `ScrollView` with the following styles and it worked just fine..

```
<View style={[styles.container, ]}
        horizontal
        style={{AlignContent: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start',}}
          style={styles.attribute}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
```

*UPDATE 1 :*

I solved the problem using this :

```
container: {
    marginTop: margin.small,
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    position: 'relative',
    width: 'auto',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    maxWidth: 29,
    height: 29,
    marginBottom: margin.big,
    borderRadius: borderRadius.base,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
```

I changed the size of option so all of them appear on the same row (not exactly what I want but it works)

If anyone have a better answer please share.